# Break words in textbox (with TextWrapping=Wrap)

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, word-wrap

I do not know how to describe my problem, but imagine having a TextBox in WPF with a long text. I have set `TextWrapping="Wrap"` to prevent the whole string being displayed in one line, but I want my sting to be shown as follows:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing el
it. Fusce ligula nulla, cursus finibus mauris vel, rh
oncus blandit sem. Fusce fermentum sed sem a porttito
r. Proin id convallis ex.
```

Instead of this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Fusce ligula nulla, cursus finibus mauris vel,
rhoncus blandit sem. Fusce fermentum sed sem a
porttitor. Proin id convallis ex.
```

*The difference is, that the first text has a 'hard cut' after every n character - the second text is wrapped, that each line does not exceed a length of n characters*

---

Do I have to insert a `\n` after every n-*th* character, or is there a WPF-property, which can solve this for me?

---

Thank you very much and merry christmas to you all :)

Comment: dosent wrapwithoverflow does this for you ?

Comment: @Muds: Unfortunatly - it doe not, SIr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct property to achieve the result. `TextTrimming` property is available only for `TextBlock`. It is better to add linebreak to achieve the result.

Answer (score 1):

> Just try it with TextAlignment="Justify"

```
<TextBox TextAlignment="Justify" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="250" MinWidth="250" Width="250" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ligula nulla, cursus finibus mauris vel, rhoncus blandit sem. Fusce fermentum sed sem a porttitor. Proin id convallis ex."/>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, it did not change the result :/

Comment: 'hard cut'  is not possible but it will add additional space to align the text